# Use date in MapSqlParameterSource in java Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate, sqlmap

I want to fetch result between start_date to end_date so that i can find my product report.

```
sql = new StringBuilder()
            .append(" select oi.last_modified,oi.product_key")                      
            .append(" from orders o join order_item oi ")
            .append(" on oi.id_order = o.id  ");
            .append(" AND o.created between '")
            .append(":start_date")  // line - 1
            .append("' and '")      
            .append(":to_date");    // line - 2
```

in both lines (line-1 & line-2)
I am trying to use prevention technique for that i am using

```
MapSqlParameterSource namedParams = new MapSqlParameterSource();
```

so for achieving this i tried lots of combination but no luck.

```
namedParams.addValue("start_date","start_date",Types.TIMESTAMP);
namedParams.addValue("to_date","to_date",Types.VARCHAR);
```

I am getting different error for different try.
i.e.

- java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date
- invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone

Comment: what is data types for :start_date and :to_date

Comment: why do you have quotes (') in your between condition?

Comment: @ThomasRisberg this is for date checker so i am using single quote.

Comment: @kuhajeyan both are timestamp data type in db

Answer (score 3):

I think it also depends on the data type of your database field. In MySQL for example there are [`date`, `datetime` and `timestamp`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html).
For me having a MySQL `datetime` and working with a java.util.Date object creating a `java.sql.Date` and specifying the `Types.TIMESTAMP` worked (`startDate` being the `java.util.Date` object):

```
MapSqlParameterSource namedParams = new MapSqlParameterSource();
namedParams.addValue("start_date", new java.sql.Date(startDate.getTime()), Types.TIMESTAMP);
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed single quote and it works for me.

```
dynamicColumnsQuery = new StringBuilder();

dynamicColumnsQuery.append("SELECT concat(TO_CHAR(months, 'MonYY'),' Adverts') AS monthYear FROM generate_series(  CAST(:fromDate");

dynamicColumnsQuery.append(" as DATE) ,  CAST(:toDate");

dynamicColumnsQuery.append(" as DATE) , '1 month' ) AS months");
```